# How to demonstrate RMSE as percentages

Tags: mse

I am doing forecasting for data, and have ended up with a RMSE of 3793.86.

I then took the mean of all the rows available and saw that it was 275007.975.

Is it correct to say that my RMSE percentage error is (3793.96 / 275007.975 * 100) = 1.38%? This is mainly for reporting purposes, as RMSE doesn't seem intuitive to management, for example.